# Reversing doubly linked list in c

Tags: c, data-structures, doubly-linked-list

I want to reverse a doubly linked list, but I am not getting the desired output with this code:

```
typedef struct node {   // structure for linked list
    struct node *prev;  // for previous node
    int data;           // for node data
    struct node *next;  // for next node
}node;

struct node *reverse(node *head){
    node *curl=head,*temp=curl->next;
    while(temp!=NULL){
        curl->next = curl->prev;
        curl->prev = temp;
        curl = temp;
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    head = curl;
    return head;
}
```

When I print the list that is returned by this function, it just prints the last node of the original list, and nothing more.

Can someone please explain what I am missing here?

Comment: Why would you want to reverse a doubly linked list?   The whole point of the list is that you can traverse it in either direction.

Answer (score 0):

The function does the job right for all nodes except the final one in the list. When `curl` is pointed to the last node in the third statement in the loop-body, then `temp` becomes `NULL` in the next statement, and then the loop exits. This means that the `prev` and `next` members of that last node were never reversed.

Once you realise this is the problem, there are several ways to correct it. I would suggest to change the order of the statements in the loop body, so that the assignment to the `prev` and `next` members comes last. Then initialise `curl` and `temp` "one step earlier" and it will work.

Unrelated, but after the loop you don't really need to assign `curl` to `head`. You can just `return curl`.

So that gives us this corrections:

```c
struct node *reverse(node *head) {
    node *curl, *temp = head;
    while (temp != NULL) {
        curl = temp;
        temp = temp->next;
        curl->next = curl->prev;
        curl->prev = temp;
    }
    return curl;
}
```